# get value out of dataframe

Tags: python, pyspark, type-conversion, apache-spark-sql

In Scala I can do `get(#)` or `getAs[Type](#)` to get values out of a dataframe. How should I do it in `pyspark`?

I have a two columns DataFrame: `item(string)` and `salesNum(integers)`. I do a `groupby` and `mean` to get a mean of those numbers like this:

`saleDF.groupBy("salesNum").mean()).collect()`

and it works. Now I have the mean in a dataframe with one value.

How can I get that value out of the dataframe to get the mean as a float number?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

`collect()` returns your results as a python list. To get the value out of the list you just need to take the first element like this:

```
saleDF.groupBy("salesNum").mean()).collect()[0]
```

Comment: Thanks, and in the case for RDD it is a two dimensional list so I could use [0][0]?

Comment: developing in ipython doesn't give me code traversing so I can learn more by going into the source code or something similar to what an ide offers.

Answer (score 34):

To be precise, `collect` returns a list whose elements are of type `class 'pyspark.sql.types.Row'`.

In your case to extract the real value you should do:

```
saleDF.groupBy("salesNum").mean()).collect()[0]["avg(yourColumnName)"]
```

where `yourColumnName` is the name of the column you are taking the mean of (pyspark, when applying mean, renames the resulting column in this way by default).

As an example, I ran the following code. Look at the types and outputs of each step.

```
>>> columns = ['id', 'dogs', 'cats', 'nation']
>>> vals = [
...      (2, 0, 1, 'italy'),
...      (1, 2, 0, 'italy'),
...      (3, 4, 0, 'france')
... ]
>>> df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(vals, columns)
>>> df.groupBy("nation").mean("dogs").collect()
[Row(nation=u'france', avg(dogs)=4.0), Row(nation=u'italy', avg(dogs)=1.0)]
>>> df.groupBy("nation").mean("dogs").collect()[0]
Row(nation=u'france', avg(dogs)=4.0))
>>> df.groupBy("nation").mean("dogs").collect()[0]["avg(dogs)"]
4.0
>>> type(df.groupBy("nation").mean("dogs").collect())
<type 'list'>
>>> type(df.groupBy("nation").mean("dogs").collect()[0])
<class 'pyspark.sql.types.Row'>
>>> type(df.groupBy("nation").mean("dogs").collect()[0]["avg(dogs)"])
<type 'float'>
>>> 
>>>
```

Comment: I have a follow-up question, dropping the link, thanks in advance! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61823544/pyspark-mapping-multiple-columns @Francesco Boi

Answer (score 8):

we can use `first()` also here.

```
saleDF.groupBy("salesNum").mean()).first()[0]
```