# How to convert a dataframe to a variable

Tags: dataframe, pyspark

Is there any direct function to convert a dataframe and assign to a variable?
For example below returns this

```
>>> partitionRecordCount= spark.sql("select count(*) from mydb.mytable where partition_date="yyyymmdd")
>>> partitionRecordCount.show()

+--------+
|count(1)|
+--------+
|  206157|
+--------+
```

---

what i need is like below

```
>>> partitionRecordCount
206157
```

I need that record count integer value directly in that variable on the left hand side  rather than a dataframe.  Please advice

Comment: In this case just do `partitionRecordCount = spark.sql("select * from mydb.mytable where partition_date='yyyymmdd'").count()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this answer
[get value out of dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38058950/get-value-out-of-dataframe)

So for your example you can just change it to:

`partitionRecordCount = partitionRecordCount.collect()[0]`

Comment: This will give below

Comment: >>> k=RecordCount.collect()[0]   
>>> k   
Row(count(1)=328694).        Not the desired intger value of 328694

Comment: Does @Rahul 's solution fit for for needs with the extra indexing?

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
partitionRecordCount.collect()[0][0]
```