# What is the correct way of selecting value from pandas dataframe using column name and row index?

Tags: python, pandas

what is the most efficient way of selecting value from pandas dataframe using column name and row index (by that I mean row number)?

I have a case where I have to iterate through rows:

I have a working solution:

```
i = 0
while i < len(dataset) -1:
    if dataset.target[i] == 1:
        dataset.sum_lost[i] = dataset['to_be_repaid_principal'][i] + dataset['to_be_repaid_interest'][i]
        dataset.ratio_lost[i] = dataset.sum_lost[i] / dataset['expected_returned_sum'][i]
    else:
        dataset.sum_lost[i] = 0
        dataset.ratio_lost[i]= 0
    i += 1
```

But this solution is so much RAM hungry. I am also getting the following warning:

"A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame."

So I am trying to come up with another one:

```
i = 0
while i < len(dataset) -1:
    if dataset.iloc[i, :].loc['target'] == 1:
        dataset.iloc[i, :].loc['sum_lost'] = dataset.iloc[i, :].loc['to_be_repaid_principal'] + dataset.iloc[i, :].loc['to_be_repaid_interest']
        dataset.iloc[i, :].loc['ratio_lost'] = dataset.iloc[i, :].loc['sum_lost'] / dataset.iloc[i, :].loc['expected_returned_sum']
    else:
        dataset.iloc[i, :].loc['sum_lost'] = 0
        dataset.iloc[i, :].loc['ratio_lost'] = 0
    i += 1
```

But it does not work. 
I would like to come up with a faster/less ram hungry solution, because this will actually be web app a few users could use simultaneously.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Coul you show a example of your dataframe and your expected output? I thin you only nned loc or at

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38058950/get-value-out-of-dataframe) will help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are thinking about "looping through rows", you are not using pandas right. You should think of terms of columns instead.

Use [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) which is vectorized (read: fast):

```
cond = dataset['target'] == 1
dataset['sumlost'] = np.where(cond, dataset['to_be_repaid_principal'] + dataset['to_be_repaid_interest'], 0)
dataset['ratio_lost'] = np.where(cond, dataset['sumlost'] / dataset['expected_returned_sum'], 0)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I did not know how to use np.where.
Your code runs in 0.002 secs.
My code used to run for 12 secs.